# Export Swagger UI documentation as an API for AWS Lambda integrated with API Gateway

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, swagger-ui, aws-lambda-powertools

Lambda contains few endpoints developed using python lambda-powertools and deployed with API Gateway.

All the required infra, Lambda, API Gateway is created through Terraform.

How to export swagger UI documentation as an api like https://customdomain.com/swagger , this url should give me the swagger UI documentation??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.